# How to plot fft in MATLAB of the signal found from software of oscilloscope?

Tags: matlab, ascii, fft, frequency, oscilloscope

I want to plot fft of signal in a matlab found from a software of oscilloscope. I can easily  plot signal in MATLAB but i am not able to plot fft in MATLAB same as found fft from software. 
There are so many questions regarding this in stack overflowbut none of those give me a suitable answer.

I am sending  the link of the image of signal found from oscilloscope's software, Plotting of this signal in MATLAB, fft of this signal using oscilloscope's software,  ascii values of these signals from oscilloscope's software respectively. Thanks in Advance!!!

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8088wYdlZ4iaHh2ak56Q1ZpSk0&usp=sharing

Comment: Any relation to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828788/ ?

Comment: Please do not create additional accounts and post duplicate questions.