# FFT does not return the amplitudes in matlab?

Tags: matlab, fft

I have generated the following time signal: 
[image]

Now I want to perform a Discrete Fourier Transform by using the matlab command `fft`

Here is my code:

```
function [ xdft, omega ] = FastFourier( t, fs )

%% Inputs from other functions %%
[P_mean, x, u] = MyWay( t )   %From here comes my signal x(t)

%% FFT %%
xdft1 = fft(x);                  % Perform FFT
xdft2 = abs(xdft1);              % Take the absolute value of the fft results
xdft = xdft2(1:length(x)/2+1);   % FFT is symmetric, second half is not needed
freq = 0:fs/length(x):fs/2;      % frequency axis

plot (freq(1:100),xdft(1:100));

end
```

And here is the plot that I get:
[image]

And what is puzzling to me is the `y` axis? Shouldn't the `y` axis represent the amplitudes of the frequency components? Is there a way to get the amplitudes of all the frequency components?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have found that some people do the following:

```
n = size(x,2)/2;      %The number of components and second half can be neglected again
xdft2 = abs(xdft1)/n;
```

This way I seem to get the amplitude spectrum, but why do I have to divide the absolute value by n?

Comment: Additional answer may be found at the related question (http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14636/how-to-get-the-fft-of-a-sine-wave)

Answer (score 2):

FFT gives you a complex pair in each Frequency Bin. The first bin in the FFT is like the DC part of your signal (around 0 Hz), the second bin is `Fs / N`, where `Fs` is the sample rate and `N`is the windowsize of the FFT, next bin is `2 * Fs / N` and so on. 
What you calc with the `abs()` of such a pair is the power contained in a bin.

you might also want to check this out: [Understanding Matlab FFT example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758315/understanding-matlab-fft-example?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Most (not all) FFT libraries preserve total energy (Parseval's theorem), which means that the magnitude has to get bigger for longer FFT windows (longer stationary waveform -> more energy).  So you have to divide the result by N to get a more "natural" looking magnitude height of sinewaves in the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the amplitudes of the harmonics, then you need to plot real(xdft1) and imag(xdft1). Real(xdft1) gives you coefficients of all the cosine harmonics present in your signal, from -Fs/2 to +Fs/2, (we assume your Fs is large enough to cover all frequencies in the signal) and the imag(xdft) give the amplitudes of the sines. 
What you are doing is giving you the *magnitude* of the signal, which is the RMS value of the total energy at a bin in both the real and imaginary frequency component. 
Its often the item of most interest to people looking at a spectrum.

Basics of this: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKNzMyS9Z6s&t=1629s)