# Fourier Transform with Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

My question is similar to, but more general than [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/7188/96528), and I think there is a mistake in there regarding normalisation, with the newest version of Matlab (2015) anyway. I hesitated to post this on CodeReview SE, if you think it would be more appropriate let me know in the comments.

I would like to **validate the following code** of a Fourier transform using Matlab's `fft`, because I have found conflicting sources of information on the web, including in the Matlab help itself, and I have been unable to verify Parseval's theorem with certain such "recipes" (including with [answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102727#answer_112072) coming from the MathWorks team, see below), especially those extracting single-sided spectra for real inputs.

For instance, the amplitude-doubling commonly found online to account for the symmetric spectra of real-valued signals when extracting positive frequencies only seems to be wrong (Parseval's theorem fails), and instead it seems to be necessary to use a square-root of two coefficient in Matlab (I don't know why). Some people also seem to normalise the DFT coefficients directly like `Y = fft(X)/L`, but I think this is confusing and should be discouraged; the amplitude is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) as the modulus of the complex DFT coefficient divided by the signal length, the coefficients themselves should not be divided. Once validated I intend to post this code as a gist on GitHub.

```
function [frq,amp,phi] = fourier_transform( time, vals )
% FOURIER_TRANSFORM computes the Fast Fourier Transform of a given time-series.
% 
% [freq,amp,phi] = fourier_transform(time,vals)
%
% Inputs:
%
%   time  - Nx1 column vector of equally-spaced timepoints (if not, input will be resampled).
%   vals  - NxM matrix of real- or complex-valued observations at previous timepoints.
%
% Outputs:
%
%   frq   - column vector of frequencies in Hz
%   amp   - corresponding matrix of amplitudes for each frequency (row) and signal (column)
%   phi   - corresponding unwrapped phase for each frequency (row) and signal (column)
%
% Note:
%   To compute the power from the output amplitude, you need to multiply by the number of timepoints:
%       power = numel(time) * amp.^2;
%
% References:
%   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

    % make sure input time-series is uniformly sampled
    assert( iscolumn(time), 'Input time should be a column vector.' );
    assert( ismatrix(vals) && size(vals,1) == numel(time), 'Input values should be a matrix with same number of rows than of timepoints.' );

    if std(diff(time)) > 1e-6
        warning('Input time-course does not appear to be uniformly sampled. Resampling before continuing.');
        [vals,time] = resample(vals,time);
    end

    % sampling information
    nt = numel(time);
    dt = time(2)-time(1);
    fs = 1/dt;
    df = fs/nt;

    % complex spectrum coefficients
    coef = fft(vals);

    % real input
    if isreal(vals)

        % extract one-sided spectrum (spectrum is symmetric)
        nfft = floor( nt/2 + 1 ); % eg 8 -> 5, and 7 -> 4
        coef = coef( 1:nfft, : );
        frq  = (0:nfft-1)*df;

        % correct amplitude values to account for previous extraction
        fac = sqrt(2);
        amp = fac*abs(coef)/nt;
        amp(1,:) = amp(1,:)/fac; % .. except for the DC component
        if mod(nt,2) == 0
            amp(end,:) = amp(end,:)/fac; % .. and for the Nyquist frequency (only if nt is even)
        end

    % complex input
    else

        % shift the spectrum to center frequencies around 0
        coef = fftshift( coef );
        frq  = fftshift( (0:nt-1)*df );
        amp  = abs(coef)/nt;

    end

    % make sure frq is a column vector and compute phases
    frq = frq(:);
    phi = unwrap(angle(coef));

end
```

---

### Example use

```
>> fs=1e3; t=transpose(0:1/fs:10); nt=numel(t); X=rand(nt,1);
>> [frq,amp,phi] = fourier_transform( t, X ); 
>> sum( abs(X).^2 ) - nt*sum( amp.^2 ) % Parseval's theorem

ans =

  -2.7285e-11
```

### Wrong example 1

From Matlab's [own example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), and [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10758315/472610) on SO:

```
>> Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 1000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
x = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);
y = x + 2*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
>> sum(abs(y).^2) - NFFT*sum(abs(Y).^2) % Parseval's theorem

ans =

 -220.4804
```

*Problem and solution:*

Comes from the normalisation in the line `Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L`. 
This should be instead:

```
>> Y = fft(y,NFFT);
Ya = abs(Y)/NFFT; % correctly normalised amplitudes
sum(abs(y).^2) - NFFT*sum(Ya.^2) % Parseval's theorem
```

### Wrong example 2

From the MathWorks team's own [clarification post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102727#answer_112072):

```
>> Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 1000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
% Sum of a 50 Hz sinusoid and a 120 Hz sinusoid
x = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);
y = x + 2*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

NumUniquePts = ceil((NFFT+1)/2);
Y=Y(1:NumUniquePts);
MX=2*abs(Y);
MX(1)=MX(1)/2; % DC component
if ~rem(NFFT,2)  % when NFFT is even, Y(1+Y/2) is the Nyquist frequency component of x, and needs to make sure it is unique.
    MX(length(MX))=MX(length(MX))/2;
end

>> sum( abs(y).^2 ) - NFFT*sum( MX.^2 )

ans =

  -5.3812e+03
```

*Problem and solution:*

Normalisation again. Replace `Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L;` by `Y = fft(y,NFFT)`, and supposedly `MX=2*abs(Y);` by `MX=2*abs(Y)/NFFT;`. But here the amplitude doubling problem appears; the correction factor seems to be `sqrt(2)` and not `2`.

### Wrong example 3

Found as an [answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45170#answer_55323) on MatlabCentral:

```
>> Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 1000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
x = 0.7*sin(2*pi*Fs/8*t) + sin(2*pi*Fs/4*t); 
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(x,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
>> sum( abs(x).^2 ) - NFFT*sum( abs(Y).^2 )

ans =

  -36.1891
```

*Problem and solution:*

As in the first example, normalisation problem. Write instead:

```
Y  = fft(x,NFFT);
Ya = abs(Y)/NFFT;
sum( abs(x).^2 ) - NFFT*sum( abs(Ya).^2 )
```

Comment: I do not have time right now for further investigations, but I noticed that for *Worng example 1*, you can (in the final line) replace `L` by `L^2 /NFFT` you get the correct result. As far as I remember Matlabs `fft/ifft` do not scale the values as it is usually done. I suggest comparing the formula given in `help fft` with the result of `fft`.

Comment: @flawr This goes along what I said about scaling coefficients directly, eg `Y = fft(X)/L`. That's a bad idea, and even an **error** when using the N-points transform `Y = fft(X,N)/L`. It should be `Y = fft(X,N)/N` instead, although again I would discourage writing this. Additionally, this does not answer the question of what the discrete amplitudes and power should be for the single-sided case.

Comment: what is the ISO (or equivalent) standard for normalizing discrete Fourier transforms and their inverse?  For example, this claim from Wikipedia: "The normalization factor multiplying the DFT and IDFT (here 1 and 1/N) and the signs of the exponents are merely conventions, and differ in some treatments. The only requirements of these conventions are that the DFT and IDFT have opposite-sign exponents and that the product of their normalization factors be 1/N.  A normalization of sqrt{1/N} for both the DFT and IDFT, makes the transforms unitary."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR (summary)

It is very hard to find online examples of `fft` usage with Matlab that normalise the amplitude/power values correctly (e.g. as can be verified with [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem)). This is crucial if you want to compare spectra between signals with different lengths. There is also an additional problem with real-valued signals because in that case the spectrum is often computed for positive frequency only, and therefore amplitude or power values need to be scaled to account for frequency-folding. **Following the post and answers below, [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/jhadida/22a08cd20913aa28ad40a8e1752993b2) which I think scales the coeffcients correctly and consistently for real- and complex-valued inputs.**

The take home messages are:

- Do NOT normalise the DFT coefficients directly (eg don't write `Y = fft(x)/L`);
- If you use an n-points transform (eg `fft(x,nfft)`), then the normaliser is `nfft` and not `numel(x)`;
- If you extract a single-sided spectrum, you need to adjust amplitude/power values depending on which correspond to conjugate pairs DFT coefficients;
- If you extract a single-sided spectrum, you should compute the amplitude and power separately (ie don't compute the power from the amplitudes).

---

### Amplitude, power and single-sided spectra

As defined and explained [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition):

- The DFT coefficients are complex and **not** normalised, while the formula for the inverse DFT carries a `1/N` factor in front of the sum. This is natural in some sense, as moving in time-to-frequency direction can be seen as a projection onto a basis of (orthogonal) waves with different frequencies, whereas moving in frequency-to-time direction can be seen as a weighted superposition of waves.
- In that superposition, the overall magnitude should be that of the original time-point (ie, it's an inversion), and the **amplitude** of each wave in that weighted average is simply the magnitude of the corresponding DFT coefficient divided by the number of waves `|Xk| / N`. Similarly, the **power** of each wave is `|Xk|^2 / N`. Matlab uses that normalisation too (well, FFTW does).
- For [real-valued inputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_real-input_DFT), the DFT coefficients are conjugate pairs for corresponding positive/negative frequencies, **apart from** the DC component (average term, frequency 0), and for the Nyquist frequency when the number of time-points is even. In practice, most applications avoid this redundancy by extracting the DFT coefficients only for positive frequencies. This leads to complications in the discrete values of the amplitude and power.
- The amplitudes corresponding to *paired* DFT coefficients (all except the first one and the Nyquist frequency when it exists) can simply be doubled and the negative frequency then discarded. Same for the power.
- Similarly for the power, but note that it is **incorrect** in that case to compute the discrete power values using the adjusted amplitude values. Indeed `N * amp_adjusted[k]^2 = N * (2*|Xk|/N)^2` is not equal to `2*|Xk|^2 / N` (this is where the square-root of two came from in the OP). Therefore it is necessary to compute **independently** the amplitude and power values from the DFT coefficients (another good reason not to scale them).

### N-points Transform

Many of the examples online use an explicit N-points transform: `Y = fft(x,NFFT)` where `NFFT` is typically a power of 2, making the computation more efficient with FFTW.

The effective difference in that case (provided that `NFFT >= N`) is that `x` is padded with 0 at its end until it reaches the length of NFFT time-points. This means that the number of frequencies in the decomposition changes, and therefore the normalisation should be done relative to `NFFT` wave components, and not the original `N` time-points.

Hence, almost all of the examples found online are wrong in the way they normalise the coefficients. It should not be `Y = fft(x,NFFT)/N`, but `Y = fft(x,NFFT)/NFFT` -- yet another good reason to loose that habit of normalising complex coefficients.

Note that this makes no difference then to Parseval's equality, because the added terms in the time-domain are all zero, and therefore their contribution to the now-larger sum is zero too. In the frequency domain though, the added discrete frequencies *will* have a response to the original signal in general, which gives an intuitive sense of why the obtained coefficients can be quite different indeed between the padded and unpadded transforms.

### Code

The code in the OP is therefore incorrect, and instead it appears to be necessary to output both the amplitude and power, as there is no general normalisation coefficient that could accommodate the complex and real cases, with even or odd number of time-points. You can find the Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jhadida/22a08cd20913aa28ad40a8e1752993b2).

Answer (score 0):

I found this online fft example ( https://habr.com/post/112068/) quite usefull. Check this out:

```
%% Parameters
Tm=5;% Length of signal (s)
Fd=512;% Sampling frequency (Hz)
Ak=0.5;% Constant component (Unit)
A1=1;% The amplitude of the first sinusoid (Unit)
A2=0.7;% Amplitude of the second sinusoid (Unit)
F1=13;% Frequency of the first sinusoid (Hz)
F2=42;% Frequency of the second sinusoid (Hz)
Phi1=0;% Initial phase of the first sinusoid (Degrees)
Phi2=37;% The initial phase of the second sinusoid (Degrees)
An=3*A1;% Noise Dispersion (Unit)
FftL=1024;% Number of Fourier Spectrum Lines
%% Generating work arrays
T=0:1/Fd:Tm;% Time Arrays
Noise=An*randn(1,length(T));% An array of random noise with a length equal to the array of time
Signal=Ak+A1*sind((F1*360).*T+Phi1)+A2*sind((F2*360).*T+Phi2);% Signal array (a mixture of 2x sinusoids and a constant component)
%% Spectral representation of the signal
FftS=abs(fft(Signal,FftL));% The amplitudes of the Fourier transform of the signal
FftS=2*FftS./FftL;% Spectrum normalization by amplitude
FftS(1)=FftS(1)/2;% The normalization of the constant component in the spectrum
FftSh=abs(fft(Signal+Noise,FftL));% The amplitudes of the Fourier transform of the signal + noise mixture
FftSh=2*FftSh./FftL;% Spectrum normalization by amplitude
FftSh(1)=FftSh(1)/2;% The normalization of the constant component in the spectrum
%% Plotting
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(T,Signal);
title('Signal');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude (Unit)');
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(T,Signal+Noise);
title('Signal+Noise');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude (Unit)');

F=0:Fd/FftL:Fd/2-1/FftL;% The frequency array of the calculated Fourier spectrum
figure();
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(F,FftS(1:length(F)));%  Plotting of the spectrum of the Fourier signal
title('Signal spectrum');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Amplitude (Unit)');
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(F,FftSh(1:length(F)));% Plotting of the Fourier signal spectrum
title('Signal spectrum');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Amplitude (Unit)');
```

Comment: Please give a citation where this is from. Just saying "online fft example" is not very helpful to others.

Comment: yes sure, I added the link. I translated the comments, since the original post is in russian