# Filtering in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering

I have EGG data regarding brain waves but want to filter it so it only shows a certain frequency (for example: alpha) how is this possible in Matlab?

I understand it may be best to use a bandpass filter, if so could you elaborate what this means?

Comment: You can use a [Butterworth band-pass filter](https://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html) for example

Answer (score 1):

Using a [Fast Fourrier Transform](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) you can choose yourself the frequency you'd like (see [explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758315/understanding-matlab-fft-example)) :

> ```
> Fs = 1000;            % Sampling frequency
> T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period
> L = 1000;             % Length of signal
> t = (0:L-1)*T;        % Time vector
> S = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);
> X = S + 2*randn(size(t));
> Y = fft(X);
> ```

Also as you mentionned see the filters -> [Filter Designer](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filterdesigner-app.html)