# MATLAB FFT Practice Problems

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to get more familiar with FFT on MATLAB so that I can begin running FFT on Physionet ECG data. I've begun that but have no way to confirm if my plot results are correct or not, so I've been looking for any type of practice problems or tutorials online where I can try it on waveforms with plot results readily available. Are there any resources where I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Recommendations for external resources are explicitly out of scope for Stack Overflow. But if you search this site, you’ll see lots of questions asking whether a given implementation is correct. Look for these questions and copy those implementations (after looking through the answers of course).

Comment: My bad, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a "practice problem", but I think the [provided documentation examples](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples.html?category=fourier-analysis-and-filtering) are always a good place to start when trying to understand MATLAB's functions. In general, I think if you spend the time to go through all the available resource on the topic of interest [(link)](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/fourier-analysis-and-filtering.html), you should be able to grasp the usage of MATLAB in those fields quite well.

Another relevant resource, might be [this SO question thread on the said MATLAB FFT example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758315/understanding-matlab-fft-example). The answers explain MATLAB's example in quite good detail.

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions that are off-topic. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic