# MATLAB FFT waveform plot with detrend and shift only has one spike

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I have some beginner, basic Physionet data I am trying to apply FFT to, but I'm a bit confused by the results I'm getting and don't think they're correct. I'm mostly using code from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758315/understanding-matlab-fft-example)  and from the [fftshift documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) with some tweaks but I'm not too sure what's wrong with my code or results. I have attached my code and snapshots of the results I'm getting.

```
load aami3am.mat

Fs = 720;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                    % Sample time
L = 60000;                   % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;               % Time vector


plot(t(1:43081),val(1:43081))
title('aami4b_h Signal')
xlabel('Seconds')
ylabel('ECG Amplitude')


NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
val = detrend(val); 
Y = fft(val,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))) 
title('FFT')


yY = fftshift(Y);
fshift = (-L/2:L/2-1)*(Fs/L);
powershift = abs(yY).^2/L;    
plot(fshift(1:L),powershift(1:L))
title('FFT Shifted')
```

[image: Original signal]

[image: fft]

[image: fft shifted]

I'm using 43081 because there are 43081 values in the .mat file over the 60 seconds of data.

Comment: By doing `fft(val,NFFT)` instead of `fft(val)` you are padding with zeros. This changes your data. You are also not windowing your data. Finally, I suggest that you plot your degreased data to make sure it’s correct.

Comment: I see, thanks! What exactly do you mean by plotting degreased data? I'm not exactly sure what this term means but it's probably my ignorance in this field.

Comment: That was meant to say “detrended”. I don’t know how that became “degreased” to my phone’s autocorrect. Sorry.